# Unix time stamp in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I use **Invoke top-level Maven targets** to make a deploy to the artifactory.

I need to use a **UNIX timestamp** as a maven deployment property in the pom.xml.

Is there a variable in Jenkins, that keeps timestamp in UNIX format? I've tried **BUILD_TIMESTAMP**, but the format is wrong. Or maybe there are any better ways to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Please, don't advice me **Promote artifactory plugin**. There are some reasons, that now allow me to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If your Jenkins runs on a UNIX system you could run a shell command and store the output in a variable:

```
def unixTs = sh(
           script: 'date -uIseconds',
           returnStdout: true
         ).trim()
```